# nodejs: multiple GET requests with async nano/express not working

Tags: node.js, express, async-await, couchdb, couchdb-nano

I have a superstrange error with node.js and express which is driving me nuts for two days now.

I want to display a series of images on my web app. Therefore, I'm sending a GET request from the client to my express API, which then should deliver the image.

It works perfectly with only ONE image per page.

However, if I want to display a series of images, let's say 8 images, ONLY THE LAST IMAGE IS BEING RENDERED! But the order changes occassionaly, sometimes it's the penultimate image that works, it's being shuffled in a complete random order!

But it's not only a problem with images - it's the same behaviour with ALL (async) requests!
For example, if I want to render some usernames to an iframe, I only get the data for the last iframe, all others show mit a 404 error with CANNOT GET.

This is my code on the frontend:

```html
<iframe src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/files/bigThumb/file-version-2017-12-27T11-53-45-647Z-3DnsDX?projectdb=cdu_regierung&companydb=cdu&authsession=supersecrettoken"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/files/bigThumb/file-version-2017-12-27T13-08-58-189Z-q52KKd?projectdb=cdu_regierung&companydb=cdu&authsession=supersecrettoken"></iframe> 
<iframe src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/files/bigThumb/file-version-2017-12-27T13-08-58-189Z-q52KKd?projectdb=cdu_regierung&companydb=cdu&authsession=supersecrettoken"></iframe> 
<iframe src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/files/bigThumb/file-version-2017-12-27T13-08-58-189Z-q52KKd?projectdb=cdu_regierung&companydb=cdu&authsession=supersecrettoken"></iframe>
```

this is my code in on the server side

```js
app.all('/files/:action/:versionId',  async function(req, res) {

try {
 
    var projectName = req.query.projectdb;
    var companyName = req.query.companydb;
    var authSession =  req.query.authsession;
  
    var nano = _nano({url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/',  cors: true, cookie: 'AuthSession='+ authSession});
  
    var session = await nano.session();
    session = session[0];
    var username = session.userCtx.name;
  
    res.send(username);
 
  } catch(err) {
    return res.status(401).send(err);
  }

})
```

My guess is that it has something to do with ASYNC function in

```
app.all('/files/:action/:versionId',  async function(req, res) {
```

as I never had this problem with standard sync function(req, res)

What am I doing wrong??

EDIT
I have them same problem with this code below.

```
app.all('/files/:action/:versionId', function(req, res) {
    request('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', function (error, response, body) {
        res.send(body);
});
```

It works perfectly with 1 GET, but not with 8 simultaneous GET requests. Also, I'm getting this error in the log:

```
_http_outgoing.js:494
throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:494:11)
```

Comment: Why are you not passing any parameters in `sendFile()`?

Comment: sorry, I copy-pasted the wrong code.

Comment: What happens if you move `var nano = _nano(...)` outside of the handler? And also have a look at [the tips here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nano#configuration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution - it's a bug caused by the nodejs middleware "express-formidable". The issue is discussed here. 
https://github.com/utatti/express-formidable/issues/6

Just use the "formidable" middleware and you're good to go.
This is the code I ended up with.

```js
var formidable = require('formidable');

// init formidable middleware
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
 var form = new formidable.IncomingForm({
  encoding: 'utf-8',
  multiples: false,
  keepExtensions: true,
 })
 form.once('error', console.log)
 form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
  Object.assign(req, {fields, files});
  next();
 })
});
```

Comment: did you do something like this `app.use(formidable())` ? can you post your working solution? I would like to see ..and also it might be useful for someone else if they run into similar issue

Comment: just avoid the module "express-formidable" and use the original "formidable" module. "express-formidable" is crap.